# How to perform regression krigin in r with dtm

Tags: r, regression, kriging, geostatistics

I would like to perform regression kriging within R, extracting elevation values from a dtm, who can advise me on which packages to use in order to best handle the elevation information of the dtm? thank you in advance for the help.